# Check for non null array during filtering an object

Tags: javascript

Trying to filter the object to return only non null values.

Below is excerpt from my code. How do I check for non null values in the array `job` in this case?

```js
const name = null,
  age = '25',
  job = [null];

const obj = {
  name,
  age,
  job
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, value]) => value)
);

console.log(result)
```

Could anyone please help?

I was expecting the result to be

```
{
  "age": "25"
}
```

Comment: Arrays are truthy.  Pop open your developer console and type `!![]`.  And even if empty arrays were falsy, yours is not empty

Comment: You will have to check `typeof` for each value and if it is an array then traverse through the array and check.

Comment: Also, what about scenarios where an array has mixed values, i.e. `['developer', null]`? Would you want to reject that array or keep it?

Comment: I will have only single value like `['developer']` @Terry

Comment: Is it possible to have a nested object? Or just arrays @coderpc

Comment: Unlike other languages, `null` is an unnatural value to use to represent "nothing in this array". It is much more common to simply use an empty array `[]` and test for emptiness. That, of course, makes programmers coming from other languages quite nervous some times.

Comment: Less smelly, if it is expected only ever be one single value, the usage of an array is unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map the array in the entries to keep only truthy values, then filter the entries by whether the entry is truthy and not a 0-length array:

```js
const name = null,
  age = '25',
  job = [null];

const obj = {
  name,
  age,
  job
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(
      ([key, value]) => [key, Array.isArray(value) ? value.filter(v => v) : value]
    )
    .filter(([, value]) => value && (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length))
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays can only have one element, you can check if the `value[0]` is truthy as well.

```js
const name = null,
  age = '25',
  job = [null];

const obj = {
  name,
  age,
  job
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, value]) => value && value[0])
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows:

```js
const name = null,
  age = '25',
  job = [null, 29];

const obj = {
  name,
  age,
  job
};
let result = {
}
for (prop in obj) {
  if (obj[prop]) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
      result[prop] = obj[prop].filter(function (element) {
        return element != null;
      })
    }
    else {
      result[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```